# PHP Json filet_get_contents not working

Tags: php, json, twitch

I'm using twitch's API for this. I'm trying to find out if the user does not exist. All the other API calls work perfectly fine except:

```
$json_array = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/'.strtolower($channelName).'?client_id='.$client_id), true);

if ($json_array['status'] == '404') {
    $errors['twitch_name'] = '* Twitch user does not exist.';
}
```

My error handling works perfectly fine, so it's not that.

Let's say that the link is going to end up being:

https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/notarealname123

Am I trying to reach the 404 error properly? Or is this 404 supposed to be called from a header of some sort?

Thanks!

Comment: need to see `file contents` to check the issue further.

Answer (score 0):

## 404 Error specific

### `$http_response_header`

`$http_response_header` is an special variable filled with an array of headers received by the latest http request (made by `file_get_contents`) and looks like (example from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php)):

```
array(9) {
  [0]=> string(15) "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
  [1]=> string(35) "Date: Sat, 12 Apr 2008 17:30:38 GMT"
  [2]=> string(29) "Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)"
  [3]=> string(44) "Last-Modified: Tue, 15 Nov 2005 13:24:10 GMT"
  [4]=> string(27) "ETag: "280100-1b6-80bfd280""
  [5]=> string(20) "Accept-Ranges: bytes"
  [6]=> string(19) "Content-Length: 438"
  [7]=> string(17) "Connection: close"
  [8]=> string(38) "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"
}
```

So the status code is inside a string at index `0`

---

You can extract the status code by using:

```
function HTTPStatusCode(){
    // Look for exactly three numbers inside headers index 0
    preg_match('/[0-9]{3}/', $http_response_header[0], $matches);
    // Return the first (should be also the only) match found in the string
    return (number)$matches[0];
}

$statusCode = HTTPStatusCode();
```

---

And then check for `404`

```
$json_array = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/'.strtolower($channelName).'?client_id='.$client_id), true);

if (HTTPStatusCode() == 404) {
    // Handle it
    $errors['twitch_name'] = '* Twitch user does not exist.';
}
```

## All Errors

Or even more general (works for every error, not just `404`):

```
$file = file_get_contents('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/'.strtolower($channelName).'?client_id='.$client_id);

// file_get_contents returns false on error
if ($file === false) {
    // Handle it
    $errors['twitch_name'] = '* Twitch user does not exist.';
}
else {
    $json_array = joon_decode($file, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is some problem with `file_get_contents`, using `curl` works fine:

```
$url = 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/'.strtolower($channelName).'?client_id='.$client_id;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$json_response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
if ($json_response->status == '404') {
    $errors['twitch_name'] = '* Twitch user does not exist.';
}
```

Comment: I'm sure the other guys answer works fine, but this worked PERFECTLY. Thank you for the copy and paste lol, you rock. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why make things more complicated than they have to be with using CURL? (It works, great but it's unnecessary, in this case) file_get_contents doesn't like errors, this is true. So than you just simplify things, check for a key that should exist, if it does, great! If it's null, well, than we ran into an error.

```
if($json_array['display_name'] == null)
{
    echo 'Sorry, ' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["channelName"]) . ' isn\'t a Twitch streamer!';
    die();
}
```

This is the code that I use in my API. Works great for me.